# Check if filename characters match outside of whitelist

Tags: string, bash, whitelist

In `bash` I'd like to test a number of directories if they contain filenames outside of what I have whitelisted:

```
[a-z]
[A-Z]
[0-9]
[+-_ßäöüÄÖÜ.,]
[ ]
```

(ie. one space is ok, two or more in a row would not).
Trying

```
$ ls my/dir/ |grep --color=always -v [a][b][c][d][e][f][g][h][i][j][k][l][m][n][o][p][q][r][s][t][u][v][w][x][y][z][A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H][I][J][K][L][M][N][O][P][Q][R][S][T][U][V][W][X][Y][Z][0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9]
```

yields all files, even the one containing a `#` character for testing.
So does the "shorthand" of

```
$ ls my/dir/ |grep --color=always -v [a-zA-Z0-9]
```

(and yes, I know I'd have to include the `[+-_ßäöüÄÖÜ., ]` characters into this later).

I have tried using `diff` for this:

```
$ diff -y <(ls -1 my/dir/) <(ls -1 /my/dir/|tr -cd '[a-zA-Z0-9\n\r \-\.\,]')|grep --color=never '|'|cut -d "|" -f 1
```

which outputs the filenames which are outside of my `tr` list:

```
A File Containing Some Rainbo#ws.wav
```

But this seems rather *clumsy*... Any ideas for something, well, *nicer*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ find -name '*[^a-zA-Z0-9+\-_ßäöüÄÖÜ., ]*' -o -name '*  *'
```

See `man find`. The `-regex` and `-maxdepth` options might also be interesting to you.

PS: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Using `find` would be my preferred way of doing it, your solutions does not show a file that contains the caharacter `#`(my test-file) though. Could you kindly elaborate on the parentheses and their meaning? I assume the `!` is a `not`? So the above reads `find where name not includes [a-zA-Z0-9+\-_ßäöüÄÖÜ.,] or where name includes two spaces`? What about multiple spaces?

Comment: @Christian Correct, it reads exactly that. I cannot tell you without further investigation why `#` does not match but I have moved the negation into the character class and now it does. Multiple spaces are not a problem since `three-spaces` is a subset of `<anything>two-spaces<anything>` (three spaces include two spaces). The parentheses are used to group expressions but I have dropped them since they are not needed here. `-o` is a logical `OR`. `[...]` is a [character class](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Shell-Pattern-Matching).

Comment: Thanks. Works as advertised -I'm very happy ;)

Answer (score 3):

Something to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

regex='^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$'
while read line
do
    if ! [[ $(basename "$line") =~ $regex ]]
    then
        echo $line
    fi
done < <(find . -type f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the start, but I think I rather go with the `find` approach below as that#s a one-shot solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls my/dir/ |grep --color=always -v [a][b][c][d][e][f][g][h][i][j][k][l][m][n][o][p][q][r][s][t][u][v][w][x][y][z][A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H][I][J][K][L][M][N][O][P][Q][R][S][T][U][V][W][X][Y][Z][0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9]
```

The above line will look for file names that don't contain the character sequence `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`, which is why it matches so many files.

try

```
$ ls my/dir/ |grep --color=always -v [^a-zA-Z0-9+-_ßäöüÄÖÜ. ]
$ ls my/dir/ |grep --color=always "  "
```

The first line looks for files that contain other characters than the white-listed ones.
The second line looks for files that contain double space.

Comment: I'll try to remember this in case I have to use `ls` and there's no `find` available.